# Install a package outside requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I am seeking a workflow advice. Let's say I am developing/modifying a python script to address one of the open issues in a repository. For some reason the package i need to develop my script is not mentioned in the `requirements.txt` and I would not like to change the existing requirements on the `master` branch.

In my case it is `jupyter-notebook` which is not in the `requirements.txt`. And when i try to do `pip install somepackage-outside-requirements.txt` it obviously complaints. I would definitely need custom classes present in the repository in my jupyter notebook.

How should I overcome this issue ? I thought of making another branch from the master and do temporary changes in requirements.txt, work on my branch and commit the changes in the python script only. Is there any other way to solve this problem ? Do you usually face such a kind of issue ?

Comment: I don't get your question. Why can't you just do a `pip install jupyterlab`?

Comment: @Selcuk Ah sorry you are right. I did a `pip install jupyter-notebook` with a hyphen and it complained (because it should be without a hyphen ) and i assumed it complaints because its not mentioned in requirements.txt. Thank you, i would delete the question its useless.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Try creating a separate virtualenv for development.

Running `pip install jupyterlab` should not affect your requirements.txt file.  You can always type `pip uninstall jupyterlab` when you're done, or create a separate virtualenv to use jupyterlab in if you're worried about accidentally adding it to requirements.txt

Comment: Unfortunately `pip uninstall jupyterlab` doesn't really cleanup after `pip install jupyterlab` because it doesn't remove dependencies. PS. The downvote is not mine.

Comment: Could you make a separate virtual env to do whatever testing you want to do in it?